# unable to open jupyter(ipython) notebook on browser

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using `python3.5` and `jupyter 4.0.6`. I launched the `jupyter notebook`, and get the following output:

```
[I 21:47:27.021 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/nitrous
[I 21:47:27.021 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 21:47:27.021 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 21:47:27.022 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 21:47:27.023 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
```

on my `firefox` browser, I typed the specified localhost url: `http://localhost:8888/` but I get `unable to connect` error message. What am I missing? is the hint of the problem on this line:

```
[W 21:47:27.023 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
```

it is my first time using the notebook. I tried to put the below code in the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file but to no avail:

```
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = True
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'firefox'
```

it also says `0 active kernels`. is that a problem?

Comment: Is the notebook server running on a different machine? Or in a virtual machine? `localhost` means 'this computer', so the default settings require it to be running on the same machine as the browser.

Answer (score 6):

If you are running your jupyter notebook in a VM (mostly on a linux vm on a windows guest) and trying to access from guest, you will need to launch Jupyter Notebook with right options. Please try to run it like below and it should work.

```
jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --no-browser
```

Please check the ip of the VM before you enter the URL in firefox. you can use

```
ifconfig
```

command for this.

Answer (score 5):

While running Jupyter on my ec2 instance I had faced the same issue.
I resolved it by executing the following command :

> jupyter notebook --no-browser

**Initially it will show 0 active kernels, once we start creating notebooks on different environments like Python,R etc it will show us the number of active kernels.**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with Chrome. I dont know in firefox but in chrome, Settings-> Enable guest browsing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem at first. I solve it by changing the following line in `jupyter_notebook_config.py`:

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = r"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe --app=%s"
```

I guess adding prefix "r" prefix to convert the string to raw string has actually solved this problem.