# How to set jupyter notebook to open on browser automatically

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

So I don't have issues trying to open the jupyter notebook but for some reason, I cannot get it to open in the browser automatically no matter what I'm trying to do. I follow these posts to no avail:
[unable to open jupyter(ipython) notebook on browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398564/unable-to-open-jupyteripython-notebook-on-browser)
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2130

I created the jupyter config through `jupyter notebook --generate-config` and modified these settings:

c.NotebookApp.browser = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = True
c.NotebookApp.webbrowser_open_new = 2

It still does not open the notebook automatically in chrome. I wonder if I am doing something stupid but I can't figure out what else to do. I am running on Windows 10 and launching jupyter through cygwin. When I type `jupyter notebook` (after modifying the settings file) in cygwin, it gives me this output:

```
$ jupyter notebook
[I 21:57:41.782 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /cygdrive/c/home
[I 21:57:41.782 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 21:57:41.782 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=373da6a3a3ed7c5fb991f0b3b1042bff22e3fa946aea8bc1
[I 21:57:41.782 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 21:57:41.799 NotebookApp]

To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
    file:///cygdrive/c/home/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-1003-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=373da6a3a3ed7c5fb991f0b3b1042bff22e3fa946aea8bc1
```

Is there anything else I can do to make it open in the browser automatically?

Update: I found this link and it doesn't work either: [Launch IPython notebook with selected browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632663/launch-ipython-notebook-with-selected-browser)

I also found that this setting was wrong: `c.NotebookApp.browser = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'`, it is supposed to be: `c.NotebookApp.browser = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'`. But I still haven't made any progress. :(

Comment: I am having a similar behavior on the WSL with windows 10. Jupyter is not openning the notebook boot but another page file:///home/user/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-232-open.html .

Comment: A temporarily hack may to launch the browser semi-automatically :): `nohup jupyter lab & sleep 5; /mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/SeaMonkey/seamonkey.exe `grep -om1 http.* nohup.out` `

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment! I couldn't figure out my problem and simply re-installed everything from scratch. By everything, I mean Cygwin, python, all my libraries, dependencies, and whatever utilities I had before. I don't know what the issue was previously but doing a simple refresh on my cygwin and python installations fixed all my problems. If you have any other suggestions for this problem, they are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I couldn't find any other solution. A recent related issue [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4594), the problem may be related to the integration with windows.

Answer (score 25):

Add this line to your `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file:

```py
c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False
```

This should open jupyter notebooks automatically in your browser with the `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` URL.

More info for the sake of completeness:

- The config file should be found in `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`. If missing can be generated (as you did) with the command: `jupyter notebook --generate-config`
- Here's the [Github issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/4999) where the change was discussed (the same solution was also highlighted [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4594#issuecomment-565805648))
- Here's the reference in the [documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html?highlight=use_redirect_file)

Comment: Thank you. For me, it was working on wsl1, but I recently moved from wsl1 to wsl2 and it is not working. Do you know why?

Answer (score 3):

At the command line, type:

`jupyter notebook --browser=<Browser>`

`<Browser>` being `Chrome`, `Safari`, `Firefox`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by setting to 'false' this setting in the config file

If not already done, generate a config file : jupyter notebook --generate-config

Then update this : NotebookApp.use_redirect_file to False (defaulted as True) in ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

(from https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html)

NotebookApp.use_redirect_fileBool

Default: True

Disable launching browser by redirect file
For versions of notebook > 5.7.2, a security feature measure was added that prevented the authentication token used to launch the browser from being visible. This feature makes it difficult for other users on a multi-user system from running code in your Jupyter session as you.

However, some environments (like Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and Chromebooks), launching a browser using a redirect file can lead the browser failing to load. This is because of the difference in file structures/paths between the runtime and the browser.
Disabling this setting to False will disable this behavior, allowing the browser to launch by using a URL and visible token (as before).

Answer (score -1):

I found a simple way to resolve this issue on any Windows OS.

Follow these steps:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run dialog box.
2. Type `%AppData%` in the box and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will take you directly to the `AppData/Roaming` folder for your user profile.
3. In the Roaming folder, navigate to `jupyter` > `runtime`.
4. Right-click on nbserver and select "Open With" to choose a browser of your choice.

See image below:

[image: f]