# Jupyter Notebook: open by URL not by file

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to set the Jupyter notebook so that at start it opens in a browser **not** by its related *html* file **but** by URL (localhost+token)?

I can of course copy and paste that from the terminal, but I am looking for a way to automatise that, as my browser won't allow me to open the html file stored locally.

Comment: Are you looking for it to trigger opening automatically? If so, then it is a duplicate possibly of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55756151/8508004) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46829761/8508004)?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to trigger automatic opening. Currently this works on IE, and I am also aware of the possibility to set the config file so that it opens on Chrome. However my browser is controlled by my institution so that it is not allowed to display html files stored locally. What I can do is copy localhost+token URL instead, and paste it in the browser. This is the procedure I would like to automatise. Unfortunately none of those two address this problem...

Comment: I value this point as on Ubuntu 22.04 firefox is now installed with snap and is thus isolated on a different partition